# Theoremstyle; leaving vertical space between the theorem header and the body of the theorem

Tags: formatting, theorems

I'm trying to write a thesis. There, they want a completely blank line after theorem, lemma, proposition, etc.. name. How can I leave such a vertical space between Theorem Head and the body of the theorem ? As an example:

> 2.1.1. Theorem
>
> Some text...

Thanks for your interest..
Best regards

Answer (score 4):

One option using [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) and a new defined style (I also used `\swapnumbers` since your example suggests that you want numbers to appear before the name):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\swapnumbers

\newtheoremstyle{newline}
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {\itshape}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%Space after theorem head
  {}% Theorem head specification
\theoremstyle{newline}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}    
A test theorem.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The [`ntheorem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) package offers you the out of the box style `changebreak`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{changebreak}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}    
A test theorem.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

The examples above will produce the head, a line break and then the body of the structure; if a complete blank line separating the head and the body is required, then you can modify my examples. For the first case, using `amsthm`, one could say something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\swapnumbers

\newtheoremstyle{newline}
  {\topsep}%Space above
  {\topsep}%Space below
  {\itshape}%Body font
  {}%Indent amount
  {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
  {\vspace{\baselineskip}}%Punctuation after theorem head
  {\newline}%Space after theorem head
  {}% Theorem head specification
\theoremstyle{newline}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}    
A test theorem.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

which will now produce

[image]

but I find this extra spacing to be odd and wouldn't recommend this style. Something similar (defining a new style) can be done using `ntheorem`.

Comment: Didn't the OP ask for a completely blank line (I know, sounds odd), these examples just show a line break.

Comment: @daleif Seems that you are right. I'll add a remark about leaving a whole blank line (I agree it's odd).

Comment: @daleif I added an example with a full blank line between head and body using `amsthm`.

Answer (score 4):

This style of theorem is already defined in the `ntheorem` package: it's the `changebreak` style. Here is a demo, with two different vertical spacings between title and text:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[thref, amsthm, thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{changebreak}

\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
Here is a test :
\begin{thm}
  This is a fundamental result
\end{thm}

\begin{prop}
  Now with a small space between title and text.
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

[image]