# How change vertical space after head in theorem-like environment

Tags: theorems, amsthm, thmtools

Is it possible when defining either the style or declaring the "theorem" to change the *vertical* spacing after the head (*not* after the entire "theorem")?

I want to do this with appropriate setting(s) in the preamble, and *not* each time I invoke the environment. (Obviously I could do it manually each time I invoke the environment.)

In the docs for `thmtools`, I did not find a key to do that either for `\declaretheoremstyle` or `\declaretheorem`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries, headpunct={}, numbered=no,
spaceabove=3\topsep, postheadspace=2em
]{exercs}

\declaretheorem[name=EXERCISES,style=exercs]{problems}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{problems}

Solve these problems.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Do this one first.
\item Solve this next.
\end{enumerate}

\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

I do strongly prefer using the `thmtools` package method of styling and declaring theorem-like environments, because it seems to give greater control over them than `amsthm` alone.

Nonetheless, even the "raw" `amsthm" approach as shown, e.g., at [Theoremstyle; leaving vertical space between the theorem header and the body of the theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222927/theoremstyle-leaving-vertical-space-between-the-theorem-header-and-the-body-of) , merely moves the beginning of the "theorem" body so as to start on a new line; it doesn't seem to allow me to add extra vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{exercises}% name
{\topsep}%Space above
{\topsep}%Space below
{\itshape}%Body font
{0pt}%Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font
{}%Punctuation after theorem head
{\newline}%Space after theorem head
{}% theorem head specification

\theoremstyle{exercises}
\newtheorem{problems}{EXERCISES}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{problems}

Solve these.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Do this one first.
\item Solve this next.
\end{enumerate}

\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This may require some kind of sorcery which should be answered soon although here is a hack but use it with discretion as I know its not even close to an answer: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\newline}{\@normalcr\@normalcr\relax}
\makeatother` Add it in your preamble. Note this may have serious consequences in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are: it was enough to consider the line break as a punctuation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries,%
headpunct={\vspace{\topsep}\newline}, %
numbered=no,
spaceabove=3\topsep, %
postheadspace=0 pt ]{exercs}

\declaretheorem[name=EXERCISES,style=exercs]{problems}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{problems}

Solve these problems.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Do this one first.
\item Solve this next.
\end{enumerate}

\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This method oK if the body of the `problems` environment has text preceding the `enumerate` list. But if not &mdash; if the body consists only of the list, then the vertical space specified in `headpunct` is ignored, and the first line of the list is on the same line as the theorem head. Yes, I know a workaround is to insert, say, `\ ` (or `\mbox{}` immediately after `\begin{problems}`, but then there is far too much space between the head and the first item of the list &mdash; the `\topskip` vertical space plus the spacing before the `enumerate`.

Comment: There is no general solution which can take into account what may happen if the theorem body is not ordinary text. In the case of a list, you can  1) load the `enumitem` package; 2) add this optional argument to the list environment: `[before=\leavevmode \vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep\relax}]`.

Comment: In my real work, I *am* using the `enuitem` package. But I think the `-` before `\dimenexpr` should not be there: otherwise, the list actually moves upward so that its first item is on the same line as the `begin{problems}` head!

Comment: Could you post a concrete example?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the collision of head with list's first line now. Your method with `enumitem` seems perfectly OK. Thanks!

Comment: I can now reliably reproduce collision of head with the list's first line. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330858/how-prevent-overwrite-of-theorem-like-head-when-showkeys-loaded .