# How prevent overwrite of theorem-like head when showkeys loaded?

Tags: enumerate, theorems, showkeys

The following source causes the "EXERCSISES" head in the theorem-like environment to be overwritten with the 1st item of the enumerated list inside:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries,%
headpunct={\vspace{\topsep}\newline},
numbered=no,
spaceabove=3\topsep,
postheadspace=0 pt ]{exercs}

\declaretheorem[name=EXERCISES,style=exercs]{problems}

\newlist{problemsenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[problemsenum,1]{%
    label=\arabic*.,
    before=\leavevmode \vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep\relax}
}

\usepackage{showkeys} 

\begin{document}

\begin{problems}
\label{myproblems}

\begin{problemsenum}

\item Do this one first.
\item Solve this next.

\end{problemsenum}

\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image: head-overwritten-by-item]

Commenting out the `\usepackage{showkeys}` *or* omitting the `\label` prevents the overwriting:

[image: output-ok]

Is there some way to prevent the overwriting even with `showkeys` loaded *and* with the `\label` still included?

One way to prevent the overwriting when `showkeys` is *not* loaded is simply to remove the newline between `\begin{problems}` and the `\label` command:

```
\begin{problems}%
\label{my problems}
```

However, even with that change, once `showkeys` is loaded the overwriting persists. Hence a more robust workaround would be desirable.

*Note:* The seemingly convoluted definition of the `problemsenum` environment is needed in order to be able to create cross-references to individual items in the `problemsenum` environment, with `\cref`, even though the theorem-like environment is unnumbered. (See [How use cleveref to get theorem-like name and list item number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327606/how-use-cleveref-to-get-theorem-like-name-and-list-item-number) and [How change vertical space after head in theorem-like environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323775/how-change-vertical-space-after-head-in-theorem-like-environment) .)

Comment: What are you trying to `\label`? There isn't anything there to refer to, is there?

Comment: The adjustment done by `showkeys` operates in horizontal mode, I *think*. However, you have put TeX in vertical mode, also I *think*. Hence, no adjustment is done.

Comment: You can put `\hskip 0pt` after `\label`. But you would be better advised to heed the recommendations provided in response to your earlier questions, I think.

Comment: Do `\usepackage[left]{showlabels}` instead of `\usepackage{showkeys}`. The `showlabels` package is usually more robust than `showkeys`. David will appreciate.

Comment: `\leavevmode \vspace` is a very weird construct, it forces the space into a vadjust node so that it is inserted after the paragraph has been broken into lines, after the first line of the paragraph.

Comment: @cfr: good question! I realize now that I no longer need any label on instances of the `problems` environment. (All problems are numbered consecutively within the chapter, not the section; with a counter `\problemnumber` reinitialized at the start of each chapter, and added keys     `after=\stepcounter{problemsenumi}\setcounter{problemnumber}{\value{problemsenumi}}` and 
    `start=\value{problem number}` in the `\setlist` for `\problemsenum`, everything else takes care of allowing cross-references to individual problems with `cleveref`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for suggestion to use `show labels` instead of `showkeys`. That allows me better control over the labels, too, e.g., to put them in the inner (in my situation, wider) margin and to print them in a smaller size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages like `showkeys` work at a quite deep level and make some assumptions about how certain things such as theorem labels are produced. In this case, your abuse of `headpunct` for inserting a `\vspace` confuses `showkeys`.

It turns out that the competitor in the field works for this special case:

```
\usepackage{showlabels}
```

This package is even more customizable than `showkeys`, so my advice is to switch. However, there's no guarantee that other complicated things like those you do here will work. In any case, both `showkeys` and `showlabels` are only used during the writing of the document, where some poor typesetting can be ignored.